# How to use session with cors origin and angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

My session work fine until i tried to allow cors.

Server:

```
  app.use(require('express-session')({
    secret: 'some key',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    proxy: true,
    cookie: {
      secure: false,
      httpOnly: false,
    },
  }));

 app.use(require('cors')());
 @Get('getUserAuthenticated')
 async getUserAuthenticated(@Req() req): Promise<{ user: User }> {
    return { user: req.user };
 }
```

And i use proxy:

```
{
    "/rest": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3000",
      "secure": true,
      "logLevel": "debug",
      "changeOrigin": true,
    }
}
```

`getUserAuthenticated` is empty when i using cors. i need it to develop purpose, so what i miss else?

Comment: Please refer to this link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SatB-55sUEM

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
{ origin:true, withCredentials:true }
```

this allows to pass cookies arround

Answer (score 0):

For someone that trying to do the same:

server:

```
  const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
    credentials: true,
  };
  app.use(require('cors')(corsOptions));
```

client:

```
get(url) { return this.httpClient.get(url, { withCredentials: true })
```